# Javascript script return errors

Tags: javascript, variables

Following code is returning error. Since I am beginner so i need to help so that i can fix the error

```
<script> 

function myFunction() { var message, x; message = document.getElementById("message"); message.innerHTML = ""; x = document.getElementById("demo").value; try { if(x == "") throw "empty"; if(isNaN(x)) throw "not a number"; x = Number(x); if(x < 5) throw "too low"; if(x > 10) throw "too high"; } catch(err) { message.innerHTML = "Input is " + err; } } 

</script>
```

Comment: `message.innerHTML = "";` is the difference. What's the actual question?

Comment: Where are the errors mentioned in the title?

Comment: what you want to say? can you elaborate?

Comment: <script>
function myFunction() {
    var message, x;
    message = document.getElementById("message");
    message.innerHTML = "";
    x = document.getElementById("demo").value;
    try { 
        if(x == "") throw "empty";
        if(isNaN(x)) throw "not a number";
        x = Number(x);
        if(x < 5) throw "too low";
        if(x > 10) throw "too high";
    }
    catch(err) {
        message.innerHTML = "Input is " + err;
    }
}
</script>
this is the original code

Comment: var message = document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "";

Comment: That still doesn't explain what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you're assigning the HTML element defined by the id "message" to the `message` variable, and then setting the `innerHTML` of that element to an empty string. It's a useful caching method if you need to, for example, change more than the innerHTML, like the style, or attribute values too.

In the second example you're doing more or less the same thing  *but*, in this case, there is no reason for you to assign it to a variable. You can simply set the `innerHTML` of the HTML itself:

```
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: Both ways of defining the variable are equal?

Comment: Yes. In the first instance all you're doing is assigning the element to a variable. It's a useful caching method if you need to, for example, change more than the `innerHTML`, like the style, or attribute values.

Answer (score 0):

```
var message = document.getElementById("message");
message.innerHTML = "";
```

In message you have an element, you can use message to manipulate it how many time you want.

```
var message = document.getElementById("message").innerHTML();
```

In that you are putting in message the string inside the inner Html

Answer (score 0):

In this case

```
var message = document.getElementById("message");
message.innerHTML = "";
```

*message* is of type[Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) (here the MDN documentation: [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)) and then you set its property *innerHTML* as `""`

but here

```
var message = document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "";
```

you create a variable named *message* and set it as the returning value of the operation `document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = ""` that, in this case, is `""`

**Conclusion:**

The first code will result in having the variable *message* as an Element object;

The last code will result in having the variable *message* as, in this case, an empty string